# Python3, Random entries into a format string problem

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, random, format

I am making a program that generates the phrase,
"The enemy of my friend is my enemy!"
actually, I want this phrase to print out a random permutation of (Friend/Enemy)
in each place every time it is re-ran.

so far I got the code to print out the same word 3 times in each,
but not a different word in each place.

I couldn't get python to access each string individually from a list.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

`

```
import random

en = 'Enemy'
fr = 'Friend'
words = en, fr

for word in words:
    sentence = f"The {word} of my {word} is my {word}!"
    print(sentence)
```

`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print random sentence each time a script is run, you can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) to choose 3 words randomly and `str.format` to format the new string. For example:

```py
import random

en = "Enemy"
fr = "Friend"
words = en, fr

sentence = "The {} of my {} is my {}!".format(*random.choices(words, k=3))
print(sentence)
```

Prints (randomly):

```
The Enemy of my Friend is my Friend!
```

Comment: The use of [`*` for iterable unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/1358308) might not be very beginner friendly, hence my version

Comment: @SamMason I agree, it's slightly advanced topic for beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make more changes to the code as it looks like the code in the question is trying to use the wrong tools.

```
import random

words = ['Enemy', 'Friend']

# three independent draws from your words
w1 = random.choice(words)
w2 = random.choice(words)
w3 = random.choice(words)

# assemble together using an f-string
sentence = f"The {w1} of my {w2} is my {w3}!"
print(sentence)
```

Not sure if this will be easier to understand, but hopefully!